# understanding integration by change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble understanding integration by the method of change of variables. Can someone elaborate the method with an example?

For instance, $\int_0^{5\pi} \frac{\sin t}{2+\cos t } dt$ using $s=\cos t$ as a new variable.

Comment: It is (somewhat) better to let $s=2+\cos t$.

Comment: ^This was the question provided in one of the course's old exams.

Comment: Have you had a look at this site for questions on substitution in integrals? There are tons of them...

Answer (score 12):

Let $f: [c,d]\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and $\varphi: [a,b]\to [c,d]$ be a continuously differentiable, bijective function (sometimes bijectivity isn't strictly required, but it's easier to prove with this assumption).  Then

$$\int_a^b f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)\ dt = \int_{c}^{d} f(x)\ dx$$

Here's an image (from an old project of mine) that hopefully shows roughly what $\varphi$ does.  $\varphi$ is a function which maps one interval (on the real number line) to another interval.

[image]

This formula is easy to [derive from the chain rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proof).

The thing that many calculus students don't understand immediately is that this formula can be run left-to-right *or* right-to-left.

**Left-to-right**
Sometimes the easiest thing to do is to manipulate our integrand until we get it into the form $f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)$.  Then we can simplify it by just setting $x = \varphi(t)$ and using the above formula.  For example, consider the integral $$\int_0^4 \frac{t}{(1+t^2)^2}\ dt$$  In this case if we realize that $$\frac{t}{(1+t^2)^2} = \frac{\frac 12(1+t^2)'}{(1+t^2)^2} = \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}\right)\left(1+t^2\right)' = \frac 12f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)$$ then we can set $x=1+t^2 = \varphi(t)$.  First we note that $\varphi: [0,4]\to [1,17]$ is bijective so then we can use our formula to simplify this integral to $$\frac 12\int_{1}^{17} \frac 1{x^2}\ dx$$ which is much easier to evaluate.  This type of substitution is called a **pushforward**.

**Right-to-left**
Sometimes it'll be easier just to compose your function $f$ with a function that has some property that'll simplify your integral.  For instance consider this similar looking integral $$\int_0^{4} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx$$ Here you can see that if you take $\varphi(t) = \tan(t)$ and compose it with the function $f(x) = \frac 1{1+x^2}$ then you'll be able to use the fact that $1+\tan^2(t) = \sec^2(t) = \cos^{-2}(t)$ to simplify this integral.  Then we just use the change of variables formula to get $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \\ \implies f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t) = \left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(t)}\right)(\tan(t))' = \frac{\sec^2(t)}{\sec^2(t)} = 1$$ That **definitely** simplifies our integrand.

But before we can set up the new integral we'll need to find the inverse of $\tan$ and check for bijectivity.  The (restricted) inverse of $\tan$ is $\arctan$.  Using that we find that the endpoints of our interval in the domain of $\tan$ should be $\arctan(0) = 0$ and $\arctan(4)$.  And we know that $\tan: [0,\arctan(4)] \to [0,4]$ is a bijection.  Then our new integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{\arctan(4)} dt$$ which is much easier to evaluate.  This type of substitution is called a **pullback**.

---

Make sure that you understand the difference between pushforwards and pullbacks.  In elementary calculus courses they both go under the title of "$u$-substitution" but they actually require different mindsets to find the appropriate substitution.  For pushforwards we try to manipulate our integrand until we recognize it as a composition of the form $f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)$ (possibly with a constant factor that we can pull out of the integral).  For pullbacks we try to find a function $\varphi$ that has properties that'll help us simplify our integral.

For the integral in your question the best approach would be to use a pushforward.  That is, if you recognize that $$\frac{\sin(t)}{2+\cos(t)} = \frac{-(2+\cos(t))'}{2+\cos(t)} = -\left(\frac{1}{2+\cos(t)}\right)(2+\cos(t))'$$ then you can use the change of variables formula.

You may notice, however, that $\phi(t) = 2+\cos(t)$ is not bijective on $[0,5\pi]$.  However it *is* bijective on $[0,\pi]$, $[\pi, 2\pi]$, etc.  See if you can figure out how to handle this on your own.  Is there some condition you see (or can guess without proof) on when $\varphi$ can be non-bijective in pushforwards?

Comment: Excellent answer! +1.

Comment: @Bye_World I had to upvote this excellent answer as I learnt something. I'd heard the terms push forward and pull back before but assumed they related to some advanced maths I had no comprehension of . I  seen the term reverse substution used too. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

$\int \frac{\sin(t)}{2+cos(t)}dt$. Let $u=2+\cos(t) \to du=-\sin(t) dt$. Now we have $\int -\frac{1}{u} du = -\ln(u) +C$. Finally the integral is $-\ln(2+\cos(t)) +C$