# Is this a $u$-substitution? Weird integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Here, $$x=\tan\theta, dx=\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$$

$$1+x^2 = 1+\tan^2\theta = \sec^2 \theta$$

So we have now that,

$$\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2} = \int \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\sec^4 \theta} d\theta$$

I have no idea what just happened. I know how to do $U$-sub, but how can you just set $X$ to be something?   Normally, you set $u=f(x)$ and go from there.  You never set $X$ equal to something.  Is this something different?

**PS:**  I tried integrating by partial fractions, and got right back to the initial integral.

Comment: If you'd like, you can think of this as the "$u$-substitution" $\theta = \arctan x$, and every substitution of the form $x = f(u)$ for an admissible function $f$ essentially works the same way (even if one can't write down $f^{-1}$ in terms of elementary functions).

Comment: Technically what you're doing is *composing* the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$ with the function $\phi(\theta) = \tan(\theta)$.  This is called a **pullback** -- where "regular" $u$-substitution is technically called a **pushforward**.  I discuss both in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575554/understanding-integration-by-change-of-variables/1575597#1575597) and again in the context of differential one-forms in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506621/the-inegral-int-12-2x-sqrtx2-1-dx-using-differential-forms/1508443).

Comment: The only composition of functions I can see is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2} ,,,and,,, g(x)=1+x^2$

Comment: What is this method called? I want to look up some tutorials and sample examples that are not as complex.

Comment: You never set $x$ equal to something... until you do.

Comment: I've never seen x used as a substitution when x is already in the equation.  The simplest traditional u-sub I can think of would be:  $y=\int\frac{1}{1+x}$  You would let $u=1+x$ and $du=dx$.   Then you would have $\int\frac{1}{u}du$ I have never seen a problem go from  $y=\frac{1}{1+x}$  to something like $x=......$    the most unnatural thing I've encountered in Calculus, so far.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not anything different.

$x$ is a real variable taking all values in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. $x$ varies from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$  whereas $\tan \theta$ takes all real values from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

So, for simplification of calculation, you can assume $x=\tan \theta$ without any loss of generality. The domain of the variable is kept intact whereas the job of integration becomes very easy by this substitution.

Comment: @JackOfAll The substitution needs to keep the domain of the variable same. And most importantly the calculation must be made easier. Which have been successfully done in this case.

Comment: @JackOfAll Why do you think this is not a u- substitution?  THIS IS a u- substitution, no doubt. Check this link .. http://brownmath.com/calc/usubst.htm

Comment: I don't see anything remotely resembling a u-sub.  There is no u=.   And there is nothing being subbed.

Comment: I've never seen x used as a substitution when x is already in the equation.  The simplest traditional u-sub I can think of would be:  $y=\int\frac{1}{1+x}$  You would let $u=1+x$ and $du=dx$.   Then you would have $\int\frac{1}{u}du$ I have never seen a problem go from  $y=\frac{1}{1+x}$  to something like $x=......$    the most unnatural thing I've encountered in Calculus, so far.

Comment: @JackOfAll Note that $u=1+x$ as you have written in your previous comment can be written as $x=u-1$. It represents the same thing. And then also $dx=du$.As for the given question, consider the substitution $u=\arctan x$ and $du=\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ which all reduce to what have been given in the problem. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are possible and used.

1) substitute $x=\phi(u)$, i.e. $dx=\phi'(u)\,du$. This gives

$$\int f(x)dx=\int f(\phi(u)) \phi'(u)du=F(u)+C=F(\phi^{-1}(x))+C.$$

2) substitute $u=\psi(x)$, i.e. $du=\psi'(x)\,dx$ or $dx=\dfrac{du}{\psi'(x)}=\dfrac{du}{\psi'(\psi^{-1}(u))}$. This gives

$$\int f(x)dx=\int\frac{f(\psi^{-1}(u))}{\psi'(\psi^{-1}(u))}du=G(u)+C=G(\psi(x))+C.$$

In both approaches you need to know the transform, its derivative and its inverse.

Comment: Just like my answer.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: I have no idea what you wrote.  Are you doing some sort of reverse chain rule?  What is this method called? I want to look up some tutorials and sample examples that are not as complex.

Comment: @JackOfAll: the notation may scare you, but actually these two processes are exactly the same.

Comment: What is the same?  Can you do your method on the example I gave above, or better yet, a simpler one?

Comment: @JackOfAll: take $x=u^2$. The rest follows.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, performing a substitution by setting the integration variable ($x$ in this case) to a function of some other variable ($\theta$ here) is far more natural that the $u$-substitution you speak of.  Why?  Because setting $x = g(\theta)$, we can find the differential $dx$ directly by simply taking the derivative $g'(\theta)$.  In contrast, the $u$ substitution *requires an inversion* of the function $u=f(x)$ before we take the derivative to find $du$ in terms of $dx$.

So, yes, setting $x$ to some $g(u)$ is much nicer than setting $u=f(x)$ in an integration by substitution.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing natural or intuitive about whatever they did.  U-sub is as natural as breathing, but this thing, I have zero clue what I am looking at.

Comment: What is this method called?  I want to look up some tutorials and sample examples that are not as complex.

Comment: @JackOfAll: I only know it as substitution.  Maybe I'll start calling it "Substitution-Without-A-Painful-Inversion" (SWAPI).  Look for this name throughout Math.SE in future integration posts.

Comment: I've never seen x used as a substitution when x is already in the equation.  The simplest traditional u-sub I can think of would be:  $y=\int\frac{1}{1+x}$  You would let $u=1+x$ and $du=dx$.   Then you would have $\int\frac{1}{u}du$ I have never seen a problem go from  $y=\frac{1}{1+x}$  to something like $x=......$    the most unnatural thing I've encountered in Calculus, so far.

Comment: @JackOfAll: Maybe when you have some time you can look through some of my answers in the (tag:integration) tag.  There you will see loads of examples of SWAPI and see how natural it is.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the basic theorem on substitution ([SEE THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definition)) states that if $g$ is a continuously differentiable function then

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\int f(g(u))g'(u)\,du$$

where $x=g(u)$.  The validity of this transformation/change of variables is a direct consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

If one begins instead with $u=h(x)$ - the "u" substitution - then one would obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int f(x)\,dx&=\int f(h^{-1}(u))\left.\left(\frac{1}{h'(x)}\right)\right|_{x=h^{-1}(u)}\,du\\\\
&=\int f(h^{-1}(u))\,\frac{d\,h^{-1}(u)}{du}\,du
\end{align}$$

where in arriving at the last line we made use of [THIS THEOREM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) in Inverse Functions and Differentiation.

---

As a request from the OP, here is a **simple example** of integration by substitution.

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.  Let $x=u^2$ so that $dx=2u\,du$.  Then, we have

$$\int \sqrt{x}\,dx=\int |u|\,2u\,du=\frac23 \text{sgn(u)}\,u^3+C=\frac23 x^{3/2}+C$$

Alternatively, we could have proceeded by letting $u=\sqrt{x}$.  Then, $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ which implies that $dx=2u\,du$.  Then, we have

$$\int \sqrt{x}\,dx=\int u\,2u\,du=\frac23 u^3+C=\frac23 x^{3/2}+C$$

as expected.

Comment: What is this method called? I want to look up some tutorials and sample examples that are not as complex.

Comment: What does "right to left" mean?

Comment: @JackOfAll Jack, it means only that in the one case we have $x=g(u)$ and proceed and in the other case we have $u=h(x)=g^{-1}(x)$. I still don't understand why this answer alone received $0$ up votes.   - Mark

Comment: Can you demonstrate your method with a basic simple example?

Comment: @JackOfAll Jack, I have edited with a simple example.  - Mark

Comment: I was told this this problem involves the technique of trigonometric substitution (and also the use of trig identities). It's a technique that can be applied to algebraic integrals where we see a term involving the sum or difference of perfect squares and where normal u-substitution doesn't work.

Comment: Jack. As I wrote, we can view the substitution either way.  In one case $x=\tan (u)$, the trigonometric substitution, while in the other $u=\arctan(x)$, the $u$ substitution.  These are in fact identical.

Answer (score 0):

I would process this integral like this:

$$\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}=\int \frac{d\arctan(x)}{x^2+1}=\int\frac{du}{\tan^2(u)+1}=\int\cos^2(u)\,du.$$

Then I know that by a trigonometric transform (double angle) this becomes trivial.