# Changing the domain of a function when integrating by $u$-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

After reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622564/is-this-a-u-substitution-weird-integral) question about $u$-substitution, it just occurred to me that integrating

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \textrm{d}x \\
$$

with $x = \cos(\theta)$ instead of the usual $x = \sin(\theta)$ seems to give the answer $-\arccos(\theta)$ instead of $\arcsin(\theta)$ which are not equivalent. Is the reason for the different answers that using $\cos$ changes the domain of the function from $[-1,1]$ to $[-1,0),(0,1]$? In general, should $u$-substitution preserve the domain of the function even though we usually substitute back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent *up to a constant*, namely $$-\arccos\theta=-\dfrac{\pi}2+\arcsin\theta.$$

Comment: Right, the plots look shifted which seems like different answers to me. For example, if the integral was defined with an interval, would the answers be different?

Comment: @totembowl They would give the same answer $\big(F(b)-F(a)=\{F(b)+C\}-\{F(a)+C\}\big)$, remember that what is shifted isn't $f\colon x\mapsto\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ itself but one of its anti-derivative.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about that pesky constant! What about the domain of the function, should I be concerned that $x = \cos(\theta)$ makes the integrand undefined at $x = 0$?

Comment: @totembowl In both cases, with the substitution $x\leadsto\cos\theta$ and $x\leadsto\sin\theta$ you're assuming that $\theta$ takes on values such that $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is defined.